# How to create a HUGE multi-dimensional array in Traditional ASP

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, vbscript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to handle a massive array in Traditional ASP, but am getting to the limits....

Essensially I need an array of (70 x Sheets, 10000 Rows, 200 Columns) to prepare an XML Spreadsheet and PDF document.

I've tried nesting dictionary objects (see below), but they are *painfully* slow.

Any suggestions at all would be greatly appreciated.....

Regards,

Paul

---

Using Dictionary Object:-

```
Dim HugeArray = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Sub AddCell(x,y,z,aText)
    Dim NewCol

    if not HugeArray.exists(x) then 
        set NewCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        HugeArray.Add x,NewCol
        set NewCol = nothing
    end if

    if not HugeArray(x).exists(y) then 
        set NewCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        HugeArray(x).Add y,NewCol
        set NewCol = nothing
    end if

    if HugeArray(x).Exists(y) then 
        set y=HugeArray(x)(y)
        if not y.Exists(z) then 
            y.Add z,aText
        else
            y(z)=aText
        end if
    end if

End Sub

Function GetCell(x,y,z)
    Dim a
    GetCell=""
    if HugeArray(x).Exists(y) then 
        set a=HugeArray(x)(y)
        GetCell=a(z)
    end if
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

just an idea: Have you ever tried to go with the json object? See [Homepage of Json](http://json.org/)
And I think the limit of the size is the memory of your webserver.

Comment: Unfortunately that just implements dictionary objects in the same manner as I've done above :o(

Answer (score 0):

did you try an excel object, perhaps it is optimized for the hevy load.
once your array is loaded and previous to "to prepare an XML Spreadsheet and PDF document" what do you need to do? sort? why the array is needed? can't you save to a temp table on db and do all dirty work there?

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd share what I did in the end....

I fed all the data into SQL Server into a temporary table as the application progressed with generating data.

Each cell was tagged with the Web Server session ID and the today's date. At the end I queried the DB to get the cells I needed to produce the report.

Each new login to the server would drop all rows < today's date (to keep it from growing)

Not necessarily the cleanest solution, but it works.